# Guice Multibindings: Manually obtain a Set<T> from Injector

Tags: java, generics, guice

Using the guice Multibindings extension one is able to inject a Set of a certain type instead of a single instance of that type. How would I obtain this Set manually from the Injector using Injector.getInstance(...)?
My attempt so far leads to a ConfigurationException with message:

> java.util.Set<T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

```
public final <T> Iterator<T> loadServices(Class<T> type) {
    final TypeLiteral<Set<T>> lit = new TypeLiteral<Set<T>>() {};
    final Key<Set<T>> key = Key.get(lit);
    final Set<T> bindings = this.injector.getInstance(key);
    return bindings.iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this snippet to create a `TypeLiteral<Set<T>>`:

```
import com.google.inject.util.Types;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> TypeLiteral<Set<T>> setOf(Class<T> type) {
    return (TypeLiteral<Set<T>>)TypeLiteral.get(Types.setOf(type));
}
```

I have a few other similar conveniences here: https://github.com/tavianator/sangria/blob/master/sangria-core/src/main/java/com/tavianator/sangria/core/TypeLiterals.java